# RegEx to find count of special characters in String

Tags: regex, string, expression

I need to form the RegEx to produce the output only if more than two occurrences of special characters exists in the given string.

1) abcd@@qwer - Match

2) abcd@dsfsdg@fffj-Match

3) abcd@qwetg- No Match

4) acwexyz - No Math

5) abcd@ds@$%fsdg@fffj-Match

Can anyone help me on this?

Note: I need to use this regular expression in one of the existing tool not in any programming language.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE after OP edit**
The edited OP introduces a small amount of additional complexity that necessitates a different pattern entirely. The keys here are that (a) there is now a significantly limited set of "special characters" and (b) that these characters must appear at least twice (c) in any position in the string.

To implement this, you would use something like:

```
(?:.*?[@#$%].*?){2,}
```

1. Asserts a non-capturing group,
2. Which contains any number of characters, followed by
3. Any character in the set `@#$%`
4. Followed by any number of characters
5. Ensures this pattern happens twice in a given string.

---

**Original answer**
By "special characters", I assume you mean anything outside standard alphanumeric characters. You can use the pattern below in most flavors of Regex:

```
([^A-Za-z0-9])\1
```

This (a) creates a set of all characters not including alphanumeric characters and matches a character against it, then (b) checks to see if the same character appears adjacent.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tzLVXP/1)

Comment: The above expression doesn't help with my requirement. I need to find if the string has any 2 occurrences of special characters which are exists in [@#$%] the range. For eg. The given string is "abc@xyz#" then it should match, because it has 2 special characters such as "@ and #". The other given string is "abc@xyz" then it should not match, because this has only one special character such as "@"

Comment: @OrionRaiders so, for my own clarity, your requirement has changed from your original post?

Comment: No esqew. My requirement still remain same. you can look into my sample expression which I provided in my original post

Comment: It appears the edit to your original post significantly changes the intentions of the pattern. I will update my answer to reflect.

Comment: @OrionRaiders I've updated my answer to better respond to your updated requirements.